# For $n \in \mathbb{N}$, if $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f|_{[-n, n]} : [-n, n] \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous then $f$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, proof-writing

I am trying to prove the following question:

> If $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is such that $f_n = f|_{[-n, n]} : [-n, n] \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous.

**Attempt:** Let $x \in [-n, n]$ and assume that $f|_{[-n, n]}$ is continuous at $x$. Then using the neighbourhood version of continuity, we have that for every open neighbourhood $V$ containing $f(x)$, there exists an open neighbourhood $U$ containing $x$ such that $f|_{[-n, n]}(U) \subset V$. Since $U$ is an open neighbourhood containing $x$, then $U \subset f|_{[-n, n]}^{-1}(V)$ is also an open neighbourhood containing $x$.

I am not exactly sure how to proceed from here after applying the continuity for open neighbourhoods. Some help would be great.

Comment: I think the proof should start, let $x$ be in $\bf R$, then $x$ is in $[-n.n]$ for some $n$, so by hypothesis $f$ is continuous at $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps it is easier to use the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of continuity. Given $x_0\in \mathbb{R}$, there exists $n$ such that $|x_0|<n$, so that $x_0\in [-n,n]$, and since $f_n$ is continuous at $x_0$, so is $f$. More precisely: given $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that if $|x-x_0|<\delta$ then $|f_n(x)-f_n(x_0)|<\epsilon$. But $f_n(x)=f(x)$ and $f_n(x_0)=f(x_0)$.

Comment: Thank you! This makes a lot more sense.

Answer (score 2):

One way to think is remark that continuity is a local propriety.
In this case, if $f$ is not continue at any point $a$, then there is any $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $a\in(-n,n)$, but then $f\mid_{[-n,n]}$ is not continue. Absurd. Hence $f$ is continue to every point $a\in\mathbb{R}$, this is, $f$ is continue.

Answer (score 1):

Pick $n$ such that $x \in (-n,n)$ and let $V$ be an open set containing $f(x)$. Since $f|_{[-n, n]}$ is continuous at $x$ there is  some open $U \subset [-n,n]$ containing $x$ such that $f(U) \subset V$.

Note that $U'=U \cap (-n,n)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$ and contains $x$ and $f(U') \subset f(U) \subset V$ and so $f$ is continuous at $x$.